# Python PyES and index to insert

Tags: python, elasticsearch, pyes

I am new to PyES, the documentation is somewhat hard to read.

I want to index data into ES and I see this:

```
conn.index({"name":"Joe Tester", "parsedtext":"Joe Testere nice guy", "uuid":"11111", "position":1}, "test-index", "test-type", 1)
```

I get the first 2 args but what are the last two?  Namely "test-type" and 1?  Where are the docs that explain the args for index as it relates to the above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**test-type** - it is like collections in a NOSQL database and In RDBMS it like tables in data base.

The last argument **"1"** is unique identifier of document.Like primary key in RDBMS and _id in NOSQL..